# Separate Towns?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I recently decided to buy the digital copy of Animal Crossing: New Leaf, and I was wondering if the towns and everything else would be separate from the cartridge that my brother plays on.

For those asking why we don't play on the same game, I wanna be mayor of my own town.

Answer (score 1):

It works the way you are hoping. The digital copy will use a different save file than the physical one, and you will both be mayors of two separate towns.

[Source](http://www.belltreeforums.com/showthread.php?66865-Are-two-towns-possible-with-a-digital-and-physical-copy-on-one-3ds)

Comment: Thanks for a quick response, I'm definitely buying it now!

Comment: @Kaisermuffin I found a source for the statement as well.